# jQuery appended element not showing up

Tags: jquery

The jQuery script is included before this script. Also, I made sure that the img src is valid. However, the `img` element is not showing up in the DOM. I've tried using both `$` and `jQuery` in case of any conflicts. However, no dice. Is there something I'm missing?

```
jQuery( ".menu-main-menu-container" ).append( "<img src='/sandbox/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/logo-tagline.png' width='102' style='margin-top: 15px;'>" );
```

Comment: Are you sure your object has a class selector and not an id? (#menu-main-...). What's the console telling? Firebug or something like that.

Comment: Without more data I would guess this is running before .menu-main-menu-container exists. Try putting it inside $(document).ready(...)

Comment: Yeah, works fine for me ... http://plnkr.co/edit/YTRQDVKhct790fTsLpL0?p=preview

Comment: @Kevin There aren't any console errors or notifications.

Comment: @jrdn That did it. Thanks.